# Why is "I go to work by my bicycle" wrong?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Why must I say

> I go to work every day with my red bicycle

and not

> … by my red bicycle"?

Shouldn't I use *by* in front of a means of transport?

For example, the following sentence is grammatical:

> If I travel to work every day, the travelling is performed **by my bicycle** and me.

And from the website, [English Teacher Melanie](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/vocabulary-how-to-talk-about-transportation/), I learned verbs can be used instead of "by".

> How do you get to work?
>
> 1. I drive to work.
> 2. … take the bus to work.
> 3. … **ride my bike** to work.
> 4. … walk to work.
> 5. … take the subway to work.

But she doesn't say "why" I cannot say: *I go to work by my red bike*.

- Why is *by* wrong in my sentence?

Comment: *By bicycle* = means of transport.  *With bicycle* still works, however, if you are trying to say something like "I put my bike in my car, drive to work, and ride bike during my lunch break."

Comment: Please spend some time checking your spelling before posting: It's "by my RED bicycle"

Comment: absolutely right! I get really annoyed myself when I see spelling mistakes. Thanks very much

Comment: Why not "on my red bicycle"?

Comment: (You wouldn't say "I go to work every day by my green Ford.")

Comment: Neither of your options is correct. Two correct options are offered below: "I go to work every day on my red bicycle" and "I go to work every day by bicycle." But to answer your question WHY? This answer is simply that certain phrases are idiomatic while others aren't. We ride in a car, but we ride on a bus. Why is that? Don't we actually ride in a bus? Yes, but we just don't say it that way. Especially when dealing with prepositions, there is often no clear reason why one is preferred over another. We often say things just because that is the way they are said.

Answer (score 3):

You can say

> I go to work every day by bicycle.

But if you use *by [method of transportation]*, the grammar requires the noun to look like a mass noun, so it can't have an indefinite article or be pluralized.  So you can say

> I travel to work every day by bus.

But you would have to say

> I travel to work every day on two busses.

Answer (score 2):

"I go to work every day *on* my red bicycle."

Comment: While technically correct, I think some explanation would be help the querent.